# Setting a keyframe value as an offset?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Let's say I have a `div` with a specified `height` of `100px` and I want to animate it so it grows by a **fixed** `20px` height.

The snippet below shows how I implemented it, successfully.

```css
@keyframes foo {
    0% {
       height: 100px;
    }
    50% {
       height: 120px;
    }
    100% {
       height: 100px;
    }
}

#foo1 {
    background-color:blue;
    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    animation-name: foo;
    animation-duration: 1.4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id='foo1'>
```

But what if I need to set the `height` property outside the CSS, so that it's not a specific value of `100px` and it can be changed to any other value, but still, I want to animate an increasing `height` of a fixed `20px` ?

Is there a way to set the animaton value as an **offset** of the original element value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the padding if you will not have any content and it's a simple visual animation:

```css
@keyframes foo {
    0%,100% {
       padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    50% {
       padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

#foo1 {
    background-color:blue;
    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    animation-name: foo;
    animation-duration: 1.4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id='foo1'>
```

Or use CSS variables:

```css
@keyframes foo {
    0%,100% {
       height:var(--h,100px)
    }
    50% {
       height:calc(var(--h,100px) + 20px);
    }
}

#foo1 {
    background-color:blue;
    
    width:100px;
    height:var(--h,100px);
    display:inline-block;
    animation-name: foo;
    animation-duration: 1.4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id='foo1'></div>
<div id='foo1' style="--h:50px;"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `keyframe` tag should have a `var(--h,100px)` value? Shouldnt it be just `var(--h)` ?

Comment: @KobyDouek yes, it's the default value that will apply in case you don't specify the `--h` so it should be everywhere when using `--h`

Comment: note about support of variables:https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way, but you have several workarounds:

- use `padding` (e.g. `padding-bottom`) to extend the element's height – only applicable if the element is not supposed to have text content flowing into the padding
- use `border` – same as above
- use an extra element, e.g. `::after`
- use JavaScript – if you are already setting the `height` "outside" of CSS, it may be that you are setting it with JS?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't solve things, I cannot use JS, the div already has padding and a border, and I cannot use psuedu elements like `after`.

Comment: @KobyDouek ok, I was going to suggest you modify the question to more clearly show this, but I think Temani's CSS variables solution is what you want.